# can't calling a class methods in laravel controller class

Tags: php, class, laravel, oop, controller

Suppose I have this code:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = new Test();

    }

    // first call this func
    public function add_name()
    {
        $this->test->add_name('name1')
        return $this->test->get_name();
    }

    // then this one
    public function show_name()
    {
        return $this->test->get_name();
    }

}

class Test
{
    protected  $name;

    public function get_name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function add_name($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

So when I call show_name() function after add_name() in `UserController`(first class), return nothing. What is my code problem?
(when calling add_name() function it work correctly)

Comment: How specifically are you calling these functions? Give us an example of your use case. Right now we just have two classes.

Comment: How do you call `show_name` function in `UserController` class?

Comment: In your `add_name` function just return only `$this->test->add_name()`

Comment: I do not see any `UserController` or `show_name` in your snippet Alireza ye aziz. Lotfan ye soal e dorost hesabi bepors :)

Comment: dahanam servis shod :) Agha class UserController ke hamin clase, show_name() ham ke esme methodeshe. @Trix

Comment: So your `$this->test` won't have a name set until you call `add_name()` so if you call `get_name()` first, it's going to return `null`. Also, controllers aren't persisted across requests so two separate requests won't have the same data in the controller

Comment: I call show_name() after add_name()!!! @Phil

Comment: if you are hitting different routes, those are different requests. Variables don't get persisted between php executions. The `show_name()` method is being called on a different request. The `add_name()` is not called in this request, you are making a call to 'new' objects.

Comment: @Alireza in the same request?

Comment: @Phil  thanks a lot. I got it. Different requests are separated from each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, It's not good practice to write separate class inside the Controller file . You have to create a separate class file in app/Classes directory . say for eg your class, Class_Test.php inside app/class. And in Your Controller file, on the top, you need to include namespace of class . Your controller function should be like .

> use App\Classes\Class_Test;

class UserController extends Controller
{

```
public function add_name()
{
   //call the class function
    Class_Test::add_name('name1');
}

// then this one
public function show_name()
{
    Class_Test::get_name();
}
```

}
Hope this Help you .